# Is there a method to rearrange symbolic expression in terms of trig function

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, simplify

Is there a method to rearrange symbolic expression `l*sin(B) + d*sin(B)` into `(l+d)*sin(B)` in MATLAB symbolic expression?

I tried to use combine and collect. Both of them don't work the way needed.

The symbolic expression is `x = d*sin(B) + l*sin(B)`, and I want to rearrange it as `x = (l+d)*sin(B)` in MATLAB live script.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found.

It work as wanted by using `collect(d*sin(B) + l*sin(B), sin(B))` rather than `collect(d*sin(B)+l*sin(B), l+d)`.